# Android app update (previous tasks)

Tags: android, sqlite, installation

Suppose I have an app installed on my device that works on an SQLite database that is created alongside the first installation do the app. Now, suppose I make some changes on a new release that involve some changes on the DB schema. Obviously, it would be desirable to make the user know that it's DB will be wiped if the new release is installed. How can I make this advertisement prior to installation so the user can take needed steps in order to lose its data?.

In short, is there a way to open a dialog advertising the user on possible data loss and letting him decide what to do?

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Comment: Why will the DB be wiped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database should have a method for updating the database

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // do something to upgrade
    }
```

But that isn't called by default, but when your app first tries to open the database. At that point, you should be to architect a dialog that instructs your user and either do the upgrade or not.

It's also possible to alter the user's database within that onUpgrade method. For example, a string like this:

```
private static final String ALTER_TABLE3 = "ALTER TABLE exercises ADD COLUMN exscore REAL DEFAULT 0.0";
```

could be used in onUpgrade like so:

```
if (oldVersion == 5) {
    db.execSQL(ALTER_TABLE3);
    // now copy all of the values from integer to real
    setUpMoveRoutine = true;
}
```

I did an upgrade from v4 to v5 that needed new elements within a table.  And then called a method to move data as needed.

You should be able to manage just about any changes in your database

Comment: onUpgrade is called automatically when you increment the database version number and access the database for the first time, there is no need to prompt the user to upgrade.

Comment: Just a silly question... Is the version number that of the app or there is a special one for the DB?. If the latter... how is this set?.

Comment: You set it yourself and pass it in the super constructor:

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to wipe the database to update the app, it's not a great user experience to do this and considering the SQLite implementation in Android is designed to allow you to upgrade the database it's also unnecessary.

Just implement the onUpgrade method in your SQLite helper class and provide upgrade steps to move between the different versions of your database.

The ALTER TABLE statements that SQLite supports are pretty limited, but you can add columns, if you need to make more complex structure changes you may need to copy data to a temporary  table drop/create your table and then insert again.